# Vigener cipher, looping the key

Tags: c

I would like to ask your help about my program. It will be a vigenere-cipher solution, but I have to encrypt it from a file.
**My problem is that I can't loop my keyword for the message length.**

There are the tasks

1. Ask the message you want to translate,maximum 255 character
2. I have to transform the message to unaccented,upper case and without spaces
3. Than print it to the screen.
4. Ask the key, maximum five character and the same transformation.
5. I have to loop the key for the lenght of the message. than print it to the screen. Now that's what I can't do.

Can somebody please help me in it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 256
#define KMAX 6

void mess(void){
    char message[MAX];
    int j,i,k=0;
    char big[]={"ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ"}, small[]={"áéíóöőúüű"}, english[]={"aeiooouuu"};
    printf("Please give the message you want to enrypt! Maximum %d character: ",MAX-1); // 1. 
    fgets(message,MAX,stdin);                                                           // 2.    
    for(i=0;message[i];i++){
        j=0;
        while(small[j] && (message[i]!=small[j] && message[i]!=big[j])){
            j++;
        }
        if(small[j]){
            message[i]=english[j]; 
        }
        if(isalpha(message[i])){
            message[k]=toupper(message[i]); k++;
        }
    }
    message[k]='\0';
    printf("\nThe clean message is: %s\n\n",message);                             
}

void keyword(void){                                                                     // 3. 
    char key[KMAX];
    int j,i,k=0;
    char big[]={"ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ"}, small[]={"áéíóöőúüű"}, english[]={"aeiooouuu"};
    printf("Please give the key!Maximum %d character\n",KMAX-1);
    fgets(key,KMAX,stdin);
    for(i=0;key[i];i++){
        j=0;
        while(small[j] && (key[i]!=small[j] && key[i]!=big[j])){
            j++;
        }
        if(small[j]){
            key[i]=english[j]; 
        }
        if(isalpha(key[i])){
            key[k]=toupper(key[i]); k++;
        }
    }
    key[k]='\0';
    printf("\nThe clean key is: %s\n\n",key);
}
void loop()                                                                           //4.
{
    
}


int main(void){                                                                            // main
    
    system("CHCP 1250");
    system("CLS");
    mess();
    keyword();
    loop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, if `big[]={"ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰ"}` uses UTF-8, `message[i]!=big[j]` will not work.

Comment: Use modular arithmetic. The key corresponding to `i`th character of the message is the `key[i % strlen(key)]`

Comment: Minor: "enrypt" sounds nasty.  Maybe "encrypt"?

Comment: To input `KMAX-1` characters **not** counting the `'\n'`, `char key[KMAX];` needs to be `char key[KMAX];...fgets(key,KMAX,stdin);` needs to be `char key[KMAX+1];...fgets(key,sizeof key,stdin);` as `fgets()` needs room for the `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

Comment: @Martin Kovál - Of course you _can't_ _loop the key for the lenght of the message_ since `message` is local to `mess` and ceases to exist when `mess` ends, as does `key` when `keyword` ends.